# Using checkboxes for multiple selection in a multi-user environment

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2010

Forgive the novice nature of this question, I am not an Access expert.

A colleague has created a database for our team. Everything works great on the whole, the database is split out and we have our own frontend access on our PC's. Record locking does not seem to be an issue as we can all go in and amend records at the same time, change any fields, EXCEPT.. when we try to amend a multiple selection checkbox. We can be in entirely different records but when we try to select from the same checkbox field in different records, in any combination, we run into problems. It's as if the table where the checkbox selection is stored is locked?

Does anyone have an explanation that I can pass on to the colleague that created it, a solution does not seem to be forthcoming.

This is the only time that we have issues, all other fields are fine in multi-user environment. Please see screen grabs below.

Selecting checkboxes:

[image: Selecting checkboxes]

Error message:

> Could not read the record, currently locked by another user:

[image: Could not read the record, currently locked by another user]

Thanks

Comment: Is `Reason Notes` a multi-valued field? Or is it a separate table?

Comment: Appears to be multi-value

Comment: Then I probably can't help. Generally this can happen if there is an event procedure behind `Reason Notes`, e.g. `AfterUpdate`, that tries to store something in the current record while it is already being edited in the form.

Comment: *Is* there an event procedure? If yes, please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Okay, there isn't an event procedure on those fields.
Would it effect it if the user had filtered the form?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this:
There are two ways you can update values from code:

- update/enter values in controls bound to database field,
- update/enter values in database

If you do both ways on single record, Access warns you with lock constraint.